EPL 2.0 and adding new files to the project
What happens when someone creates a fork of a library under EPL 2.0, and this fork modifies some files and adds some new files?
I can see that the modified files should retain EPL2 license, but what about new files "inside" the library (e.g. new implementations of some internal interfaces). Are they required to be EPL2 too?
Could someone point me to the portions of the license text that explains it?
